# Can "if" be replaced by "when" in the following sentence

Tags: conditionals

Can "if" be replaced by "when" in the following sentence:

"If teenagers get pregnant while they are still in high school, they might encounter financial difficulties later on in life."

I'm familiar with the "possible/unreal situation or condition" for if, and the required certainty for when, but I still cannot figure out whether "when" can be used.

Comment: Is there no difference between when and if in your language?

Comment: @Lambie in at least some languages (biblical Hebrew being one) the word for "if" and "when" are the same (although the multiple meanings of the same word are acknowledged).

Answer (score 1):

"When" can be used, because it's a certainty that it does happen that teenagers sometimes get pregnant when they are in high school. You can also use "if". It's a slight difference in perspective that doesn't affect the overall meaning in that sentence.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!